# Adding a -Recurse option to my powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have a function which acts on a single filesystem item and I would like to add the ability to recurse the filesystem as an option, similar to Get-ChildItems -Recurse.
I've read that GCI recurse has problems when it encounters a directory it has no permissions to read, throws an exception and stops.  I'm wondering what's the best way to do it.

Should I;

1. Add Pipelining to my function and perform:  `gci -Recurse $path | edit-mydetails -Add "my comment"`
2. Add a recurse switch to my function and implement directory recursion,  using GCI internally:  `edit-mydetails -Recurse -Path c:\users\me\Documents\MyProject -Add "My details"`

using this conditional logic block;

```
...
    if ($Recurse) {
        gci -Recurse -Path $Path | % { do-stuff $_.Name }
    } else {
        do-stuff $Path
    }
...
```

3. Some other more robust method of walking the filesystem, using System.IO ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've read that GCI recurse has problems when it encounters a directory it has no permissions to read, throws an exception and stops.

No: By default, [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) does *not* stop when it encounters an error during traversal: it emits a *non-terminating* error and *continues*.

You can use the common `-ErrorAction` parameter to modify that behavior, notably `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress error *display* while still collecting errors in the automatic `$Error` variable, `-ErrorAction Ignore` to quietly ignore errors altogether, and `-ErrorAction Stop` to indeed stop processing at the first (non-terminating) error encountered.

Additionally, you can use `-ErrorAction <variable-Name>` to collect all errors in a designated variable, except if you also specify `-ErrorAction Ignore`.

> Should I:
> Add Pipelining to my function and perform: `gci -Recurse $path | edit-mydetails -Add "my comment"`

Yes, you should: there is no good reason to *duplicate* the functionality of `Get-ChildItem [-Recurse]` inside your function. Instead, make your function accept `[System.IO.FileInfo]` input and optionally also file-system path strings via the pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with a try-catch:

```
try{
 gci -Recurse -Path $Path | % { do-stuff $_.Name }
catch{
 ### Filter out the bad folder and try again
    gci -Recurse -Path $Path -filter "Path -ne '$badPath'" | % { do-stuff $_.Name }
}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` only ever emits _non-terminating_ errors (except if the invocation is syntactically incorrect), so a `try` / `catch` statement has no effect (except if you also use `-ErrorAction Stop`).